# Can I use arduino and mobile phone screen to make a touch board?

Tags: events

I'm new to Arduino, I want to use Arduino and a mobile phone screen to make a simple touch board.

This phone screen I mean, is like this:

[image]

Can I connect it to Arduino, and when my fingers touch the screen, Arduino can get the events?

Comment: From what I can tell, Nintendo DS screens are easy to inference (they even have breakout boards) and very cheap, but they are resistive, thus they need pressure to use. They aren't the kind on a iPhone, and are only one touch point.

Comment: Without details we can't answer the question.  You will need technical specs and/or a datasheet for the screen.

Answer (score 1):

First, find a suitable phone screen! Good luck. Most of the touch screens that I have found are resistive, and will never feel like an iPhone. Try googling "Arduino touch screen". Adafruit have a promising one.

Once you find your screen, you will need to interface to it. With luck it will come with a pre-built library. Otherwise you will be up for quite a lot of coding.